# How to make my package signatures match previously installed version?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm deploying my Delphi 11.3 app to an Android device that has the app store version of the app installed. I get this error:

> Package com.bookup.chessopeningswizard signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

I need to test how the published app behaves when it is updated (for example, whether it retains user-created documents).  I'm simulating this by deploying the updated project from Delphi.

How do I get Delphi to match the signatures of the previously installed app from the play store?

Uninstalling the previously installed app is not an option, as I want to test how the app behaves when updated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the "easiest" ways would be to deploy for Play Store, and use the bundle tool to extract the `.apk` which could then be copied to/installed on your device. You can execute the bundle tool at the command line - assuming you have the same JDK as me and a default install of Delphi 11, it would look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.14.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\Android\bundletool-all-1.2.0.jar" build-apks --bundle="path\to\your\app.aab" --output="path\to\your\app.apk" --ks "path\to\your\playstore.keystore" --ks-pass=pass:yourpassword --ks-key-alias=youralias --mode=universal
```

Where you replace the obvious parts with your own info, i.e.:

`path\to\your\app.aab` is the path/filename of the `.aab` file for your app

`path\to\your\app.apk` is the path/filename of the `.apk` file that is output when extracted

`path\to\your\playstore.keystore` is the path/filename of the `.keystore` file you used for deploying in app store mode

`yourpassword` is the password for the `.keystore` file

`youralias` is the alias used for the `.keystore` file